# Passing messages from multiple activities to main activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

It's quite hard to get my problem across but here goes.

I have one activity *Activity 1* which from this I can open one of three activities *Activity 2*, *Activity 3* and *Activity 4*, of which I want a result to come from *Activity 3*. Within each of these activities I can create a new intent to open any of the other activities, in turn calling `finish()` on the current activity.

I have the code working for when I open *Activity 3* from *Activity 1* and then press the button to finish *Activity 3* it sends the message perfectly. My problem lies in say opening *Activity 2* from *Activity 1* then from *Activity 2* opening *Activity 3* (in turn calling `finish()` on *Activity 2*) and then pressing the button in *Activity 3* and sending the same message to *Activity 1*. At the moment the result code sent through is 0, when I am trying to get it to send the result code '726'.

In summary I want to be able to send messages from an Activity created from an intent from an unknown level of other Activities, but the message always goes back to the same lowest level Activity if that makes sense.

I am sorry if this is hard to understand and I hope somebody can help me

Comment: Is this the activity [scheme](http://i.imgur.com/YIh9f.png) you describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions but I figured it out anyway for anybody else looking for the answer:

**From the Main Activity**

```
 public void onClick2Activity(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(1Activity.this, 2Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==726){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            int string = bundle.getInt("test");
            Log.v("Extra", "" + string);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**From 2Activity:**

```
    public void onClick3Activity(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(2Activity.this, 3Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==726){
            Intent in = new Intent();
            in.putExtra("test", "test");
            setResult(726,in);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Log.v("Failed", "Failed");
        }
    }
```

**From 3Activity:**

```
public void onItemClick(){ 
    Intent in = new Intent();
    weaponID = position  + 1;
    in.putExtra("test", "test");
    setResult(726,in);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with answering your own question! You are even encouraged to if you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Also [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) will do the work.

Or [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult) on many levels (Activities).